# SMPP delivery report

Tags: smpp

How to check for the *delivery report* of the sent message. I am using PHP and I have the SMPP account. Can somebody help me with the checking of delivery report?

Will I get a delivery report as message like we get in our mobile?
Or the status of the send function will do for it?

Answer (score 6):

Using SMPP you can retrieve *delivery report* in the following ways.

First choice is to set **registered_delivery** parameter to `1` when you send `submit_sm` PDU.
In this case [SMSC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short_Message_service_center) should send you `deliver_sm` PDU with `esm_class = 0x04` containing *delivery report*.

Other way is to request delivery status with `query_sm` command but this may generate more traffic if polling SMSC too often.

Comment: Any example on python?

Comment: @Gustavo Piris, the language doesn't matter.. just get an SMPP class and apply what he told you, you could think of the first choice as a normal message on phone, you set the reports to on and when the msg is delivered the provider will send you a delivery report. You just read that using the `deliver_sm` command.

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking about the format in which the **Delivery_Receipt** will be delivered back to the source then it's carried as the user data payload in the SMPP `deliver_sm` or `data_sm` operation.

The following fields are relevant in the  `deliver_sm`  and `data_sm` operations when used for transmitting delivery receipts:

```
• source address (i.e. source_addr_ton, source_addr_npi, source_addr)
• destination address (i.e. dest_addr_ton, dest_addr_npi, destination_addr)
• esm_class
• message_state
• network_error_code
• receipted_message_id
```

Comment: Hi..
How to change the message_state.?
Where its changing point.?

Comment: @Priyanka Hi. I am sorry but since it has been more than 4 years since I answered this question and haven't worked with SMPP for the same amount of time, I really can't remember anything on that topic. :)

Comment: thankx 4 comment. i got it.its handled by DeliveryInfoSender class :-)

Comment: Any example on python?

Comment: @GustavoPiris Example of what exactly?

Comment: That i need is to can read the inbox of a smpp with python, i have the code to send sms but now i need to read the messages that received on the server

Answer (score 1):

SMS *delivery receipts* are regular SMS text messages generated by SMSC, but `esm_class = 0x04` is used to differentiate them. The `esm_class = 0x04` means [PDU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protocol_data_unit) direction is [SMSC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short_Message_service_center) → [ESME](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_Short_Messaging_Entity) and short message contains SMSC *delivery receipt* short message.

Short message area of `deliver_sm` SMPP PDU consists below text format which is encoded using `dcs=0x00` [*data coding scheme*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Coding_Scheme) (i.e. SMSC Default Alphabet according to the [SMPP specification](https://smpp.org/)):

```
id:{message_id} 
sub:{message_sub}  
dlvrd:{message_dlvrd}
submit date:{message_submit_date} done  
date:{message_done_date} 
stat:{message_stat} 
err:{message_err}
```

Sample delivery receipt message text:

```
id:40072910491427628 sub:001 dlvrd:001 submit date:1007291049 done date:1007291049 stat:DELIVRD err:000
```

Adding the following link here for details of processing the sample message above:

- [SMS Delivery Reports with SMPP protocol](https://www.smssolutions.net/tutorials/smpp/smppdeliveryreports/)